# Python playsound error 263: The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI

Tags: python, playsound

I'm trying to play a sound with the python library `soundplay`.

I saw other questions on Stack Overflow, but I haven't found a valid solution for my problem.

Here is the piece of code that should play the sound:

```py
from playsound import playsound

playsound('./folder/sound.mp3')
```

This is the error:

```
playsound.PlaysoundException:
    Error 263 for command:
        open ./folder/sound.mp3
    The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI
```

I've also tried uninstalling `pysound` and installing its latest version, but the error doesn't change.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading to playsound 1.2.2 worked for me. Just run :

`pip install playsound==1.2.2`

No more issues afterwards

Comment: It worked for me too

Comment: I also updated auto-py-to-exe to make it work

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a file system issue. When the code runs in the playsound module, it doesn't recognize the *relative* path you entered. Instead, you need to enter an *absolute* path.

Try:

```
import os
current_dir = os.getcwd()
file_path = current_dir + '/folder/sound.mp3'
```

Alternatively:

```
import os
file_dir = os.path.dirname('./folder/sound.mp3')
file_path = file_dir + '/sound.mp3'
```

Comment: at last it doesn't work but is probably an error in my system (it doesn't work only in my pc), a good alternative is pygame.mixer